# Creating a C++ Class Instance for every server request?

Tags: c++, oop, irc

Me and my team are writing an IRC server in C++ for a school project and we are hung up on the question of performance vs readability when it comes to working with client requests. Basicaly we receive an input, where the first word will determine, which command is then called on the server, and in IRC, different commands have different syntaxes.

Idea 1: We have a Class called Command, and subclasses for each type of command. As they have different syntax, you have to "tokenize" every command differently. Everytime a request arrives, an instance of Class Command will determine the Subcommand, whose class instance will be created to finish "tokenization".

Idea 2: We have a Class called Command, one instance will be created throughout the entire time the server is active. Whenever we receive a request with a command we just reassign the variables within the instance.

Idea 3: We just go monolithic for processing the commands. We determine the command to be called based on the first word, then in a function we just split the string, and implement the command.

One part of the team says, that Idea 1 is too heavy and produces too much load per request that renders the server inefficient. the other says, that although it does have a slower performance, the other ideas are messy and the Class structure of Idea 1 introduces more readability and easier maintainability.

Comment: `One part of the team says, that Idea 1 is too heavy and produces too much load per request that renders the server inefficient` i want to see the benchmark numbers supporting that broad claim, otherwise just go with whatever is simplest to implement and satisfies the requirements , premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: if you are going with Idea 1, note that you can create a `thread_local` object pool for each type of `Command` and a factory that creates objects from those pools, and minimize the number of `virtual` functions you have to reduce their overhead, and it will have almost no overhead compared to Idea 3.

Comment: Unless you are planning to serve/handle millions of requests/commands per second, I very much doubt that the performance of an *optimized* build of either option will actually matter. Go with the simplest and easiest to maintain approach.

Answer (score 3):

The advantage of approach 1 over approach 3 is readability and less mental anguish.

If you were to ask "Hey, where is the code for Broadcast Message handled?" The answer for approach 1 would be: "It's in the `BroadcastMessageCommand` class."; approach 3 is: "It's somewhere in this massive single function called `HandleCommands`. Good luck."

Readability over performance until proven otherwise WITH PROFILING AND MEASURING is my go-to. That all said, this question is way too opinion-based and may be closed outright anyway.